# Rendering as a Small White Screen

Tags: rendering

So I'm following the classic donut tutorial and I'm stuck on the rendering phase. I've moved my camera around, I've moved the lighting, my scaling is a 1, everything is there. I have no clue why this won't render. Before I messed with the camera, it was a very small pixelate donut bc the camera was too far away.
Any tips? I've been googling and took a break and still can't get it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you type '0' in the 3D Viewport, do you see the donut centered in the framed area.  Looks like it should be but camera may be pointing to one side the donut.

Comment: You might also decrease your, "Clip Start," clipping distance on your camera, as it might be culling the front of the doughnut that is near the camera origin.

Comment: How small is your donut? It looks tiny - like 1/10 the size of the camera - maybe scale both the icing and the donut up by 10 or so (applying scale afterwards, of course). After this, you can center the camera on the donut and set its position by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Numpad0.